# How do I Replace Faces with .obj?

Tags: python, modeling, add-on

I've been trying to export .obj Minecraft worlds with custom .json and .obj models for every block by editing [jmc2obj](http://jmc2obj.wikia.com/wiki/Jmc2obj_Wiki) code and it kinda worked.

Then thought of doing something different but I don't know how to do it, I have a theory of what could make this work, (something like [McPrep's Mesh Swap](http://theduckcow.com/dev/blender/mcprep/)

My idea is to replace each individual face for another model, the way it would work is by using the face's normal lines as a way to tell blender to replace and center the model

[image]

Since it is replacing faces we need 6 objetcs one for each face

[image]

(for this block all faces are the same)

for example, if the face normal is facing at +x the face gets replaced by the object "stone_brick +x" or if it is facing at -y it gets replaced by the object "stone_brick -y" and so on until we cover all 6 faces

this would only work for cubes as for different models it shouldn't work, like fences, anvils, and any other model that has more than 1 face per axis

Comment: Parent the Objects to the Cube then in the Cube Mesh properties select Duplicate and Faces. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html

Comment: @rob it worked! I just need to find a way to hide the plane and the object without hiding the duplicate or find a way to make duplicates into a mesh

Comment: cool! select the parent  :Object ‣ Apply ‣ Make Duplicates Real

Comment: oof I didn't get a notification or I would have replied earlier, anyway now I'll start creating the script so it's just 1 click action